# Two column layout in twitter bootstrap with first column a fixed width, the second column width fills the rest of the space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I am trying to get the layout as described in the title.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span12">
  <div class="fixed_width"></div>
  <div class="variable_width"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
div.fixed_width {
 width: 300px;
 // or try with: "float:left;" too
}

div.variable_width {
 overflow: hidden;
 // if you use float:left in the other, don't use overflow here, but try with: "width:100%;"
}
```

Here you can find a more general example (http://jsfiddle.net/glee/6Cavr/)